# Convert an object of an interface to its base interface

Tags: typescript

```
interface IPerson {
    firstName: string;
    lastName:  string;
}

interface IPersonWithPhone extends IPerson {
    phone: string;
}

const personWithPhone: IPersonWithPhone = {
    firstName: "Foo",
    lastName: "Boo",
    phone: "+1 780-123-4567"
}
```

Lets say `IPersonWithPhone` extends `IPerson`. I want to convert `personWithPhone` to a `person`, meaning `personWithPhone.phone = undefined`. I don't want mutate the object, at the same time I don't want to set each property separately. Something like below,

```
// Not like this
const person: IPerson = {
    firstName: personWithPhone.firstName,
    lastName: personWithPhone.lastName
}
```

I am looking for something similar to spread, that can remove a property and can convert to the base interface.

```
// example of spread
cont person: IPerson = {
    firstName: "Foo",
    lastName: "Boo",
}

const personWithPhone: IPersonWithPhone = {...person, phone: "+1 780-123-4567"};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type information doesn't exist at runtime, so no magic solution here. You'll need to specify which properties you'd like to omit.

One of the options is [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring):

```
const personWithPhone: IPersonWithPhone = {
    firstName: "Foo",
    lastName: "Boo",
    phone: "+1 780-123-4567"
}

const { phone, ...person } = personWithPhone;
```

Here `phone` property of `personWithPhone` goes to `phone` variable and all the [rest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Rest_in_Object_Destructuring) into `person`

Comment: `object destructuring` is exactly what I was looking for. I know about it, but I could not think of using in this case. You are right, it should work here! Thanks